# Ошибка с локальной переменной game, пожалуйста объясните в чем суть ошибки

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, переменные, область-видимости

Ошибка с локальной переменной `game`. Пожалуйста, объясните в чем суть ошибки.

```
class Players_team():
    def __init__(self, name, team):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.damage = 20
        self.health = 100
    
    def get_hit(self):
        self.health -= self.damage
    def Health(self):
        return self.health
        
    def dead_health(self):
        if self.health == 0:
            return f'{self.team} team {self.name} is dead!'

blue = Players_team('Rimuru', 'Blue')
red = Players_team('Hong', 'Red')

import random
game = True
def game_b():
    while game:
        for i in range(1, 11):
            j = random.randint(1, 2)
            if j == 1:
                blue.get_hit()
                print('Blue under attacked',blue.Health())
            elif j == 2:
                red.get_hit()
                print('Red under attack',red.Health())
            if blue.health == 0:
                print('Blue team is dead')
                game = False
                break
            elif red.health == 0:
                print('Red team is dead')
                game = False
                break
            
def olimp_bet():
    game_b()
    make_deb = input('Chose team! Blue or Red')
    if make_deb == 'Blue':
        if blue.health == 0:
            print('You lose')
        else:
            print('You win')
    elif make_deb == 'Red':
        if red.health == 0:
            print('You lose')
        else:
            print('You win')
            
a = olimp_bet()
```

Comment: Чтобы принять наиболее полезный ответ, надо поставить галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

В функции `game_b()` имеем локальную переменную `game`, зона видимости которой
будет только эта функция `game_b()`.

Вы к ней обращаетесь, а она еще не объявлена.
Вы и получаете ошибку `обращаетесь до присвоения`.

```
import random


class Players_team():
    def __init__(self, name, team):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.damage = 20
        self.health = 100
    
    def get_hit(self):
        self.health -= self.damage
    def Health(self):
        return self.health
        
    def dead_health(self):
        if self.health == 0:
            return f'{self.team} team {self.name} is dead!'

blue = Players_team('Rimuru', 'Blue')
red = Players_team('Hong', 'Red')

#import random
#game = True
def game_b():
    game = True                                                       # <---
    while game:
        for i in range(1, 11):
            j = random.randint(1, 2)
            if j == 1:
                blue.get_hit()
                print('Blue under attacked',blue.Health())
            elif j == 2:
                red.get_hit()
                print('Red under attack',red.Health())
            if blue.health == 0:
                print('Blue team is dead')
                game = False
                break
            elif red.health == 0:
                print('Red team is dead')
                game = False
                break
            
def olimp_bet():
    game_b()
    make_deb = input('Chose team! Blue or Red')
    if make_deb == 'Blue':
        if blue.health == 0:
            print('You lose')
        else:
            print('You win')
    elif make_deb == 'Red':
        if red.health == 0:
            print('You lose')
        else:
            print('You win')
            
a = olimp_bet()
```

Answer (score 0):

Все переменные используемые внутри метода должны либо объявляться внутри метода, либо передаваться в нее как параметр. Говоря простым языком, метод game_b() не в курсе происходящего за его пределами. Метод срабатывает только тогда когда его вызывают, например game_b(). Передача параметра game решает проблему:

```
class Players_team():
    def __init__(self, name, team):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.damage = 20
        self.health = 100
    
    def get_hit(self):
        self.health -= self.damage
    def Health(self):
        return self.health
        
    def dead_health(self):
        if self.health == 0:
            return f'{self.team} team {self.name} is dead!'

blue = Players_team('Rimuru', 'Blue')
red = Players_team('Hong', 'Red')

import random
game = True
def game_b(game):
    while game:
        for i in range(1, 11):
            j = random.randint(1, 2)
            if j == 1:
                blue.get_hit()
                print('Blue under attacked',blue.Health())
            elif j == 2:
                red.get_hit()
                print('Red under attack',red.Health())
            if blue.health == 0:
                print('Blue team is dead')
                game = False
                break
            elif red.health == 0:
                print('Red team is dead')
                game = False
                break
            
def olimp_bet(game):
    game_b(game)
    make_deb = input('Chose team! Blue or Red')
    if make_deb == 'Blue':
        if blue.health == 0:
            print('You lose')
        else:
            print('You win')
    elif make_deb == 'Red':
        if red.health == 0:
            print('You lose')
        else:
            print('You win')
            
a = olimp_bet(game)
```